# GET Request on Docker Traefik API - Block by CORS rules

Tags: docker, get, traefik

I've got trouble finding how to reach my Traefik API using GET request from an other docker container.

**Context**

I have 2 docker container, one running a traefik instance :

```
docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -p 8080:8080 -p 80:80 -l traefik.frontend.rule=Host:my.server -l traefik.port=80 --name traefik traefik --docker --api
```

The other container run a quite simple React web application. I'm trying to reach the Traefik API using *XMLHttpRequest*.

My request is blocked by the Traefik CORS Policy. Any idea on how configure Traefik to enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin ?

Answer (score 4):

The only way I've done this is by wiring the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header as a label in the Træfik container.

```
traefik.frontend.headers.customResponseHeaders=Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

And if you need to add more headers like `Access-Control-Allow-Method`, you must concatenate them with double bars (`||`) in the same rule.

```
traefik.frontend.headers.customResponseHeaders=Hdr1:val1,val2||Hdr2:val3
```

So your *docker run* line would be as follows.

```
docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
-p 8080:8080 -p 80:80 \
-l traefik.frontend.rule=Host:my.server \
-l traefik.port=80 \
-l "traefik.frontend.headers.customResponseHeaders=Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*" \
--name traefik traefik --docker --api
```

Comment: David, which Traefik version you're using? Rules syntax have changed. I gotta update this post.

Comment: I am using Traefik 2.2, but I reconfigure all stack and all works now